# Trying to separate two elements

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to separate these two elements using a CSS sheet. I want the img on the top left of the page and the words on the top right. I tried using the ids for each element but since they are all under the first id, and I am not allowed to change the HTML code, the img and the words both move to the right or both move to the left.

```css
#picture {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div>
    <img id="picture" src="./img/bag.png" alt="notif">
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
  </div>
  <div>I am saying hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "*I've been trying to separate these two elements using...CSS*" - how, exactly, have you tried to do this? Can you share your attempted code, that way we can see your attempt, reproduce your problem, and hopefully explain why your approach failed in order that you - and others, in future - learn something useful.

Comment: #picture {
    margin: 0 auto;
} 

#header {
 background-color: blue;
 text-align: right; 
}
But then both elements move to the right but I want the img on the left and all of the text on the right

Comment: I've added a demo to your question, does that demo (click 'run') reproduce your problem accurately?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `float` property;

```css
#picture {
  float: left;
}

#header {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div>
    <img id="picture" src="./img/bag.png" alt="notif">
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
  </div>
  <div>I am saying hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because elements with `float` are removed from the normal flow - so they don't affect and are not affected by other elements. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)